# Explicit expression for Fredholm determinant.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a rank $2$-matrix, i.e. there are vectors $v_1,v_2,w_1,w_2$ such that

$$Ax = \langle v_1,x\rangle v_2 + \langle w_1,x \rangle w_2.$$

I wonder if there is an explicit expression for the Fredholm determinant

$$\operatorname{det}(1+A).$$

On wikipedia we have a Taylor series for the determinant, but the expression is hard to interpret for me with this wedge product [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_determinant#Definition)

Answer (score 0):

If we actually treat $A$ as an $n \times n$ matrix and so treat $v_1,v_2,w_1,w_2$ as elements of $\Bbb C^n$, then we have
$$
Ax = (v_2v_1^* + w_2w_1^*)x
$$
(where $M^*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose of $M$), so that
$$
A = v_2v_1^* + w_2w_1^* = \pmatrix{v_2 & w_2}\pmatrix{v_1 & w_1}^*.
$$
From the [Sylvester determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity), we have
$$
\det[I + A] = \det \left[I + \pmatrix{v_1 & w_1}^*\pmatrix{v_2 & w_2} \right]
 \\
= \det
\pmatrix{1 +\langle v_1,v_2\rangle & \langle v_1,w_2\rangle\\
\langle w_1,v_2\rangle & 1 + \langle w_1,w_2\rangle}
\\ = (1 +\langle v_1,v_2\rangle)(1 + \langle w_1,w_2\rangle) - \langle v_1,w_2\rangle\langle w_1,v_2\rangle.
$$
The same should hold for operators over a Hilbert space.